# Qual é atualmente a linguagem (ou linguagens) rica em recursos considerada de instalação mais simples no Windows?

Tags: windows, instalador, ambiente

*(Mais uma pergunta com cara de off-topic para a coleção)*

Instalar ambientes de desenvolvimento para linguagens de programação nem sempre é fácil. Java e Ruby, por exemplo, são linguagens que na minha experiência para você ser capaz de por pra rodar algum código útil dão um certo trabalho.

Isso é particularmente verdade no Windows, onde não costumam vir instaladas e onde não costuma haver (pelo menos não historicamente) um *package manager* incluído.

Qual seria hoje a linguagem (ou linguagens) em que esse esforço se reduz ao mínimo, no caso do Windows? Nem falo de IDE, falo só de ter compilador/interpretador para rodar na linha de comando mesmo.

Em Linux é mais fácil. É comum já vir o `gcc` (C), `gpp` (C++) e Python instaladas nas distros populares, entre outras menos usadas que servem para *one-liners*, como `awk` e `sed`.

Estou considerando as linguagens poderosas e expressivas, shell script não conta.

Acho que a coisa mais fácil de vir é o JavaScript que vem em qualquer navegador para qualquer sistema. Já para ter na linha de comando deve dar um pouco mais de trabalho, sei que o NPM é um *package manager* popularmente usado para suas dependências mas nunca instalei para saber quão complicado é.

Estou pensando em linguagens que sirvam tanto para programar desktop como para programar web. Python por exemplo poderia vir a ser uma ótima candidata, se for fácil de instalar nesse sistema.

Quanto mais popular melhor, mas se tiver umas não tão populares na ponta da língua aproveita e compartilha aí também.

Comment: Pronto, [uma sala exclusiva para debater o assunto](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/119786/discussion-on-question-by-piovezan-qual-e-atualmente-a-linguagem-ou-linguagens)